# Detecting DisplayPort (vs. DVI?) on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics

I'd like to determine if a (currently active) display is attached via DisplayPort or not (for my purposes, I can assume a display not connected via DP is a DVI connection.)  Is there any Windows API for getting this information?

I didn't see any information on how to approach this at displayport.org, although Wikipedia did mention that I could read some information from the EDID.  I also have found some code fragments on using the WmiMonitorID System.Management interface from C# (either a .NET or C++ solution would be fine), but this doesn't seem to provide that detail.

Solutions that require NVidia or ATI-specific extensions would be acceptable as well, provided they work with their current offerings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution using the [WmiMonitorConnectionParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb980612(v=VS.85).aspx) class.  The **VideoOutputTechnology** field maps to the [D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546605.aspx) enum.

On initial testing, I get a D3DKMDT_VOT_DVI return for a notebook system, and a D3DKMDT_VOT_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL from a DP-connected display.

e.g.

`using System.Management;`

...

```
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
                "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorConnectionParams");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WmiMonitorConnectionParams:");
                foreach (PropertyData pd in queryObj.Properties)
                {
                    string name = pd.Name;
                    string val = pd.Value.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", name, val );
                }
            }
```

This seems to work - but I'd still be interested in any other approaches.